# Error in HSD Tukey test in R

Tags: r

I am working with a one way anova and want to run a posthoc test. I keep getting an Error:

> Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") : 
>     no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "function"

I still cannot find a solution.

My Data looks like this:

```html
Treatment IND
T 1 7
T 1 7
T 1 10
T 1 5
T 1 10
T 1 10
T 1 12
T 1 8
T 1 1
T 1 8
T 1 14
T 1 9
T 1 10
T 1 10
T 1 6
T 1 9
T 1 9
T 1 11
T 1 2
T 1 6
T 1 5
T 1 9
T 1 11
T 1 9
T 1 7
T 1 12
T 1 11
T 1 8
T 1 10
T 1 9
T 1 11
T 1 9
T 1 4
T 1 9
T 1 11
T 1 11
T 1 9
T 1 12
T 1 13
T 1 11
T 1 9
T 1 10
T 1 7
T 1 7
T 1 8
T 1 11
T 1 1
T 2 7
T 2 8
T 2 5
T 2 8
T 2 4
T 2 5
T 2 3
T 2 3
T 2 4
T 2 4
T 2 5
T 2 4
T 2 5
T 2 6
T 2 4
T 2 8
T 2 7
T 2 5
T 2 6
T 2 6
T 2 3
T 2 7
T 2 4
T 2 4
T 2 4
T 2 6
T 2 5
T 2 6
T 2 6
T 2 3
T 2 5
T 2 5
T 2 7
T 2 7
T 2 5
T 2 3
T 2 6
T 2 6
T 2 7
T 2 7
T 2 5
T 2 3
T 2 7
T 2 6
T 2 8
T 2 5
T 2 7
T 2 5
T 2 6
T 3 7
T 3 11
T 3 8
T 3 10
T 3 7
T 3 10
T 3 10
T 3 6
T 3 9
T 3 8
T 3 7
T 3 14
T 3 9
T 3 8
T 3 15
T 3 13
T 3 5
T 3 9
T 3 9
T 3 10
T 3 10
T 3 12
T 3 13
T 3 10
T 3 9
T 3 10
T 3 7
T 3 9
T 3 9
T 3 11
T 3 7
T 3 11
T 3 7
T 3 11
T 3 9
T 3 10
T 3 7
T 3 5
T 3 9
T 3 10
T 3 11
T 3 12
T 3 11
T 3 9
T 3 9
T 3 4
T 3 7
T 3 6
T 3 4
```

Then the ANOVA result is:

> oneway.test(IND~Umsiedlung)

```html
 
One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  IND and Treatment
F = 52.778, num df = 2.000, denom df = 86.334, p-value = 1.063e-15
```

The Tukey posthoc test:

> tukey.test<--TukeyHSD(x=oneway.test(IND~Umsiedlung),conf.level=0.95)

tukey.test

```html
Error in UseMethod("TukeyHSD") : 
  no applicable method for 'TukeyHSD' applied to an object of class "htest"
```

Is anything wrong with my command or dataset? I know this is a very primary question... but if anyone could help me, it would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TukeyHSD works with aov class objects which result from the function `aov`. The function `oneway.test` returns an object of class htest. That is the reason of your error. If you want to run `TukeyHSD` you need to use `aov`

using your data:

```
TukeyHSD(aov(lm(IND ~ Treatment, data = df1)))

  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = IND ~ Treatment, data = df1)

$`Treatment`
            diff        lwr       upr    p adj
T2-T1 -3.2726878 -4.3935451 -2.151831 0.000000
T3-T1  0.3803734 -0.7404838  1.501231 0.701296
T3-T2  3.6530612  2.5439410  4.762181 0.000000
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Treatment = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3"), 
                      IND = c(7L, 7L, 10L, 
5L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 14L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 
11L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 
9L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
11L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 
14L, 9L, 8L, 15L, 13L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 9L, 
10L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 4L)), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -145L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help phiver!